# Google Analytics: Direct traffic after Paid Search override

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads-api

I have a question about how Google Analytics interprets different sessions. 
Let's say a customer visits my website by clicking on a link in Google search results(paid search or organic search). The customer then bookmarks my website and visits it after a few days and places an order making a transaction in Google Analytics.
The question is: would the transaction be counted as the result of direct traffic or search engine traffic? And if not is there any way to count it as search engine traffic?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your setup but as standard it would be tracked as a search transaction.
You can check your setup by going to Admin > Tracking Info > Session Settings. Here you can change your campaign timeout settings.

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2795871?hl=en